# Как вывести с помощью меню в окне?Можно ли его как-то добавить шаблонные функции и проверку ввода и сделать код меньше?

Tags: c++

Помогите решить задачу на C++ в классах.

Задача

Автоматизированная информационная система на железнодорожном вокзале содержит сведения об отправлении поездов дальнего следования.

Для каждого поезда указывается:

• Номер поезда
• Станция назначения
• Время отправления

Данные в информационной системе организованны в виде линейного списка.

Составить программу, которая:

• Обеспечивает первоначальный ввод данных в информационную систему и формирование линейного списка
• Производит вывод всего списка
• Вводит номер поезда и выводит все данные об этом поезде
 вывод в обратном порядке
• Вводит название станции назначения и выводит данные обо всех поездах, следующих до этой станции

Программа должна обеспечивать диалог с помощью меню .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class cTrain{
        int iNumber;
        string sDestination;
        string sDepartureTime;
public:
        cTrain(){
                iNumber = 0;
                sDestination = "";
                sDepartureTime = "";
        }
        cTrain(int iNumParam, string sDestParam, string sTimeParam){
                iNumber = iNumParam;
                sDestination = sDestParam;
                sDepartureTime = sTimeParam;
        }
        int iGetNumber(){
                return iNumber;
        }
        cTrain(cTrain const &copy):iNumber(copy.iNumber), sDestination(copy.sDestination), sDepartureTime(copy.sDepartureTime){}
        string sGetDestination(){
                return sDestination;
        }
        string sGetTime(){
                return sDepartureTime;
        }
        void operator =(cTrain objRight){
                iNumber = objRight.iNumber;
                sDestination = objRight.sDestination;
                sDepartureTime = objRight.sDepartureTime;
        }
};

void _AddTrain(vector <cTrain> &vSource){
        int iTempNumber;
        string sTempDest, sTempTime;
        cout << "Number of the train: ";
        cin >> iTempNumber;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Destination: ";
        getline(cin, sTempDest, '\n');
        cout << "Arrival time: ";
        cin >> sTempTime;
        cin.ignore();
        vSource.push_back(cTrain(iTempNumber, sTempDest, sTempTime));
}


void _PrintList(vector <cTrain> &vSource){
        if (vSource.empty()){
                cout << "List is empty!";
                return;
        }
        vector <cTrain>::iterator iterSource = vSource.begin();
        cout << "Train number Destination Departure Time\n\n";
        while (iterSource != vSource.end()){
                cout << iterSource->iGetNumber() << '\t' << iterSource->sGetDestination() << '\t' << iterSource->sGetTime() << '\n';
                iterSource++;
        }
}

void _GetTrainInfo(vector <cTrain> &vSource){
        if (vSource.empty()){
                cout << "List is empty!";
                return;
        }
        vector <cTrain>::iterator iterSource = vSource.begin();
        bool bIsFound = false;
        int iTrainToSearch;
        cout << "Input train's number: ";
        cin >> iTrainToSearch;
        cin.ignore();
        while (iterSource != vSource.end()){
                if (iterSource->iGetNumber() == iTrainToSearch){
                        bIsFound = true;
                        cout << iterSource->sGetDestination() << '\t' << iterSource->sGetTime() << '\n';
                }
                iterSource++;
        }
        if (!bIsFound)
                cout << "No such train was found";

}

void _GetStationInfo(vector <cTrain> &vSource){
        if (vSource.empty()){
                cout << "List is empty!";
                return;
        }
        vector <cTrain>::iterator iterSource = vSource.begin();
        bool bIsFound = false;
        string sStationToSearch;
        cout << "Input station's name: ";
        //cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, sStationToSearch, '\n');
        while (iterSource != vSource.end()){
                if (iterSource->sGetDestination() == sStationToSearch){
                        bIsFound = true;
                        cout << iterSource->iGetNumber() << '\t' << iterSource->sGetTime() << '\n';
                }
                iterSource++;
        }
        if (!bIsFound)
                cout << "No such station was found";

}

int main()
{
        vector <cTrain> vDataBase;
        char cKey;
        do{
                system("cls");
                cout << "1 - Add info about new train to the Database\n";
                cout << "2 - Show Database\n";
                cout << "3 - Show info about specific train\n";
                cout << "4 - Show info about arriving trains to the station\n";
                cout << "5 - Exit\n";
                cKey = _getch();
                system("cls");
                if (cKey == '1'){
                        _AddTrain(vDataBase);
                }
                else if (cKey == '2')
                        _PrintList(vDataBase);
                else if (cKey == '3')
                        _GetTrainInfo(vDataBase);
                else if (cKey == '4')
                        _GetStationInfo(vDataBase);
                else if (cKey == '5')
                        cout << "Goodbye";
                else
                        continue;
                _getch();
        } while (cKey !='5');

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если код не компилируется, укажите ошибку в вопросе.

Comment: Опишите в чем состоит проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существование поезда  не зависит от пункта назначения и времени отправки, поэтому пусть поезд имеет номер и открытые поля для записи времени отправки и станции назначения.

```
class Train{
    int iNumber;
public:
    std::string sDestination;
    std::string sDepartureTime;
    explicit Train(int num = 0) : iNumber(num) {}
    int get_number() const { return iNumber; }
    // обеспечим способ вывода  данных поезда
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Train& t)
    {
        os << "номер поезда : " << t.get_number() << '\n'
           << "станция назначения : " << t.sDestination << '\n'
           << "время отправления : " << t.sDepartureTime ;
        return os;
    }
};    
class Info_system {
    std::list<Train> info;  // все поезда
    class Cmp1  {           // функтор по станции назначения
        const std::string s;
    public:
        Cmp1(const std::string& dest) : s(dest) {}
        bool operator ()(const Train& t) { return t.sDestination == s; }
    };

public:
    // добавить в информационную систему поезд с данными
    void add(int num, const std::string& dest, const std::string& time) {
        Train t(num);
        t.sDestination = dest;
        t.sDepartureTime = time;
        info.emplace_back(t);
    }
    // вывод информации о поездах следующих до станции dest
    void show_train(const std::string& dest, std::ostream& os)  const
    {
        std::copy_if(info.begin(), info.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Train>(os, "\n"),
                     Cmp1(dest));
    }
     // найти в системе поезд с номером num
    const Train  get_train(int num) const
    {
        auto It = find_if(info.begin(), info.end(),
                          [&](const Train& t) { return t.get_number() == num; });
    // если нет такого поезда, возвращать поезд без номера
        return (It != info.end()) ? *It : Train();
    }
    // вывод информации о всех поездов
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Info_system& i)
    {
        std::copy(i.info.begin(), i.info.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Train>(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{    
    Info_system  is;
    is.add(3, "A", "13:03");
    is.add(5, "B", "12:15");
    is.add(7, "A", "14:30");
    // информация о поездов, следующих до станции "A"
    is.show_train("A", std::cout);
    // обеспечим некоторый диалог через консоль
    std::cout <<"\nвведите номер поезда для получения информации \n" ;
    int k;
    while (true) {
    std::cin >> k;
    Train t = is.get_train(k);
    if (t.get_number()) {
        std::cout << t;
        break;
    }
    else
        cerr << "Нет поезда с таким номером. Введите номер снова\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Остальной диалог обеспечьте сами по своему вкусу и представлению